# Magento Block Override - Call to a member function error

Tags: magento, overriding

I am trying to override this block:
/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/View.php

with this:
/app/code/local/Poulin/Fees/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php

In /app/code/local/Poulin/Fees/etc I have the following code in my config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
     <Poulin_Fees>
         <version>0.0.1</version>
     </Poulin_Fees>
 </modules><global><blocks>
<catalog>
<rewrite>
    <product_view>Poulin_Fees_Block_Catalog_Product_View</product_view>
</rewrite>
</catalog></blocks></global></config>
```

In /app/code/local/Poulin/Fees/Block/Catalog/Product/View.php I have the following code:

```
class Poulin_Fees_Block_Catalog_Product_View extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View
{

  public function justTesting()
  {
    return 'just testing';
  } 
}
```

Please help what am I missing?